# EF other way to Sum() new Column

Tags: entity-framework

i got stuck on this query that calculate the new column.
i cannot explain briefly just see the snippet code below.

```
from user in context.Table
select new 
{
    Total = user.Total,
    Paid = user.Paid,
    Balance = //should be Total - Paid to assign result
}
```

i have tried this query

```
var result = from a in context.EnrollmentRequests
                         where a.SchoolYear == SchoolYear
                         select new
                         {
                             a.StudentID,
                             Name = a.Student.FirstName + " " + a.Student.MiddleName + " " + a.Student.LastName,
                             Tuition = context.Miscs.Where(m => m.YearLevel == a.YearLevel && m.SchoolYear == SchoolYear && m.Term == a.Term && m.CourseID == a.CourseID)
                                                .Select(ms => new { Amount = ms.Amount })
                                                    .Union(context.StudentCharges
                                                        .Where(s => s.YearLevel == a.YearLevel && s.SchoolYear == SchoolYear && s.Term == a.Term && s.CourseID == a.CourseID && s.StudentID == a.StudentID)
                                                            .Select(ss => new { Amount = ss.Amount }))
                                                                .Union(context.StudentSubjectTakes
                                                                    .Where(st => st.StudentID == a.StudentID && st.SchoolYear == a.SchoolYear && st.Term == a.Term && st.YearLevel == a.YearLevel && st.EducationalLevel == a.Student.StudentAdvanceEducations.FirstOrDefault().EducationLevel)
                                                                        .Select(st => new
                                                                        {
                                                                            Amount = context.SubjectOfferedFees
                                                                                .Where(f => f.SubjectsOfferedID == st.SubjectsOfferedID).Sum(w => (decimal?)w.Cost ?? 0)
                                                                        }))
                                                                                .Select(f => f.Amount).Sum(),
                             PaymentMade = context.Payments.Where(p => p.SchoolYear == SchoolYear && p.Term == a.Term && p.StudentID == a.StudentID && p.PaymentDes == "Tuition Fee").Sum(sm => (decimal?)sm.Amount),
                             Balance = Tuition - PaymentMade //Does not exist on current context
                         };
```

but doesn't work it says that does not exist on current context.

how could this possible.
thanks. this will be helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Balance = user.Total - user.Paid

Comment: thank you for answering but the problem is iv'e assigned another query on column Total and Paid.

like Total = context.Table2.Where(f=>f.Id).Select(s => s.Amount).Sum()

Paid = context.Table3.Where(f=>f.Id).Select(s=>s.PaymentAmount).Sum()

on my current i got long long lambda query for that, so im looking for the shortest way.. hmm your answer still right..